# ionic ng cordova TypeError: "Cannot read property 'printer' of undefined"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaPrinter, ) {

```
$scope.print = function() {
  console.log('print method here');
     var page = document.getElementById('print_id');
      if($cordovaPrinter.isAvailable()) {
          $cordovaPrinter.print(page, 'Document.html', function () {
          alert('printing finished or canceled')
          });
        }
}
```

Give me any suggestion regarding this error.
Thanks

Comment: Describe what you want to do.

Comment: i want  print some content from a page but css not loading with element.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same error.
I re-install plugin using :  `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-printer`
and install again using : `cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer.git`
and then finally `cordova build`